# can't remove android backHandler

Tags: react-native

I find this code to handle the back button on android :

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.handleAndroidBackButton ();
}
componentWillUnmount () {
  this.removeAndroidBackButtonHandler();
}
handleAndroidBackButton = () => {
  BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
    this.showModal1(true);
    return true;
  });
};

removeAndroidBackButtonHandler = () => {
  BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {});
}
```

it works  fine but when I go to the other page, I still have the same behaviour. 
I find this on stackoverflow:

```
constructor() {
   this._onBackButton= this._onBackButton.bind(this)
}
_onBackButton() {
   return true;
}
```

and I changed my code to this:

```
     constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      transData: [],
     ...
    }
    this._onBackButton = this._onBackButton.bind(this);
  }

 _onBackButton = () => {
    return true;
 };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.handleAndroidBackButton();

    ...
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    this.removeAndroidBackButtonHandler();
  }

  handleAndroidBackButton = () => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this._onBackButton);
  };

  removeAndroidBackButtonHandler = () => {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this._onBackButton);
  }
```

I don't have any error now but it doesn't work ! it doesn't remove event listener in other screens

Comment: where is your `_onBackButton ` handler ?

Comment: the function ? directly after the constructor method . I edited my code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AndroidBakHandler you're having is named `_onBackButton`  ... but you're binding a method called `_onBack` ... So just rename your backHandler to be `_onBackButton` and make it **arrow-function** (Auto bound to your class ... that's why you wouldn't need to bind it in the constructor)

```
// constructor() {
// No need for the next line ... arrow function is bound automatically
//        this._onBackButton = this._onBackButton.bind(this);
//  }

 _onBackButton = () => {
    return true;
 };
```

-

```
removeAndroidBackButtonHandler = () => {
  BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress',
                                   () => {}); // <- look at that
}
```

**Regarding: "It works fine but when I go to the other page, I still have the same behaviour."**

It's because when you navigate into another screen (Your component is **not unmounted**) ... and you're removing your android-back-handler in `componentWillUnmount` ...

So I'd suggest you remove your event-listener **when you navigate to another screen** not in `componentWillUnmount`

Also make sure you have you add your android-back-handler when your screen receives focus again

Comment: I would recommend that you add some explanatory text to your answer, or you risk having it deleted as 'low quality' (even though it may be a correct answer)!

Comment: I just forget to change it but it doesn't work, and I changed my _onBackButton function to an arrow function and still not workin, giving me tha same error !

Comment: @zedArt Same error ?? `undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this._onBack')` ?? ... and you're saying you changed it to _onBackButton ?

Comment: non this time  undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this._onBackButton') and I change the place of calling it in constructor, first time it was on top befor super(props) but now I put it after states... I will redit my code check it please

Comment: oh thank you I will try it and tell you if it works but just one more thing, when I click on back button I have to show a modal (look my first code) but now I can't, because I call this._onBqckButton instead, how can I call my function to show a modal please

Comment: @zedArt if you tried to apply my solution ... things should work as it's and you should see you modal popped up on android-back-btn-press :)

Comment: but I don't know when put my function to show modal, please edit your response if you can with showModal() function